# Stop motion sci-fi kids show

Tags: story-identification, tv

I’m trying to recall a kids show (possible kids show or even movie?)

I remember a few details but cannot think of its name. I’m under the assumption the show is based off of a surrealism artist who did sci fi landscapes and creatures ect. (Can’t remember his name)

The show involved a group of random space creatures - the captain, a mechanic that lived on the ship who looked like a green rat/lizard with black hair and a long tail and I’m positive he had a Scottish accent - he wore blue overalls . One had butterfly wings and the captain kind of resembled a garden gnome?

I remember one episode they land on a swamp/marsh planet and there was frog like beaked aliens that had long tongues and spoke with a hillbilly accent and carried trumpet like guns. They shot their tongues out like frogs at them.

The show was possibly stop motion/claymation? I remember it all loosely resembling the dark crystal.

It wasn’t Plasmo.

Comment: Any additional information you can provide will assist others in helping you find this. Do you remember when you saw it? Did it seem like something that was new or something older that was being shown again? What country were you seeing it in? What language was it in? Do you recall anything that would indicate whether that's the original language it was created in, or that it was dubbed into that language? If possible, do you remember what channel you saw it on (or, if it was recorded, whether it was VHA tape, DVD, bluray)?

Answer (score 3):

This is *[Lavender Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavender_Castle)*, produced by Gerry Anderson, who also did *Thunderbirds*.

> Lavender Castle is a place of mystery and legend, fabled throughout the universe, a floating city of light, a place of peace, harmony and all the things that have ever been dreamt of. It is the centre of the universe and the greatest source of power - should it be destroyed, the universe would be plunged into darkness forever. Evil scientist Dr Agon plans to do just that. A lonely megalomaniac with technology-assisted powers of transmutation, he yearns for darkness and has pledged to destroy Lavender Castle from his fortress spaceship, the Dark Station, the most destructive power in the universe, crewed by unseen slaves working deep in the bowels.
>
> In order to prevent this, Captain Thrice has set out on a quest to find the elusive Lavender Castle before Agon does and protect it at the same time. A previous encounter with Lavender Castle gave life to Thrice's walking stick and left the Captain with a special knowledge of its power and abilities. Travelling in his cottage spaceship, the Paradox, Thrice assembles a crew of misfits to join him in his quest, combatting evil wherever they find it as they travel the universe searching for clues that will lead them to Lavender Castle. But Lavender Castle works in mysterious ways and lends its power to the Paradox crew to protect them when they most need help.

Captain Thrice indeed looks like a garden gnome. Isenbard the engineer wears blue coveralls and has a Scots accent. Lyca has butterfly wings on her helmet.

I found it with a search of *"stop motion" tv series alien crew scots accent*, which brought up [this list](https://www.eskimo.com/%7Erkj/l.htm), and I started searching the names of items listed as stop motion.

### The first episode - "In the Beginning"

You can see Dr. Agon's trumpet weapon in use in the episode. It shoots red blasts that burn and strike with concussive imapct.

Comment: Should you return, you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.